# Trying to fill VLOOKUP in VBA, but lookp only works for 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to write a VBA code thta helps me Vlookup value from another location on C Drive, but apparently only the first two cells work.

Could you help me correct this code? Really new to VBA and just trying my waters with the Do While Looops.

```
Sub Copy3()

    Dim lookfor As Range
    Dim table_array As Range
    Dim table_array_col As Integer
    Dim lookFor_col As Integer
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Dim Rows As Integer

    Rows = 2
    Do While Rows < 60

    Set lookfor = Cells(Rows, 1)

    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XXX.xlsx")
    Set table_array = Wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:H60")
    table_array_col = 5

    lookFor_col = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count - 2
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows, lookFor_col).Formula = Application.VLookup(lookfor.Value, table_array, table_array_col, 0)

    Rows = Rows + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a formula to the cell, or a value? Then note that `Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XXX.xlsx")` (and other lines) should be *outside* the loop.

Comment: Also consider consistent casing, and avoid snake_case. Then change all those `Integer` to `Long`.... there's no benefit to using `Integer` here, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error. `Set lookfor = Cells(Rows, 1)` was missing a qualifier, and was likely not referencing the correct workbook. `Workbooks.Open` changes the Active Workbook. Unqualified ranges are prone to cause errors when the Active Workbook changes during execution.

I corrected that by adding a reference to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and also cleaned up some other minor problems that I noticed. Notably, Rows is one of the Range Objects built into Excel VBA. Its best to avoid using defined object names as your variable names when you can.

```vb
Sub Copy3()
    
    Const table_array_col As Integer = 5
    
    Dim lookfor As Range
    Dim Row As Integer
    
    Dim lookFor_col As Integer
    lookFor_col = Sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 2
    
    Dim Wbk As Workbook
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XXX.xlsx")
    
    Dim table_array As Range
    Set table_array = Wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:H60")
    
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Row = 2 To 59

        Set lookfor = Sh.Cells(Row, 1)
        
        Sh.Cells(Row, lookFor_col).Value = Application.VLookup(lookfor.Value, table_array, table_array_col, 0)
    
    Next Row
End Sub
```